# Saving cookie-denial in a cookie

Tags: session, cookies

Stack Overflow!

I have a question for the EU Law about storing cookies.

My website stores their choice of language in a cookie. But they can turn those off ofcourse. Then the language will be stored in a session.

I have to questions here:
1: Is it ok to store the session in a cookie (Like: PHPSESSID)? 
2: Is it ok to save their request to not use cookies in a cookie, so that it won't ask the next time?

I am sorry if this is a stupid question, I just want to be as userfriendly as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not a stupid question -- far from it -- but it's unlikely you'll get a definitive answer, either here or anywhere else.

The "EU cookie law" is mandated as a *directive*, that is, an instruction to EU member states to implement national legislation that meets the EU's broad objectives. So to get the exact regulations you'll have to find the corresponding legislation in the jurisdiction you operate. In the UK, this is the Privacy and Electronic Communications (EC Directive) (Amendment) Regulations 2011.

The legislation will almost certainly not be easy to follow, and a proper understanding will require access to other legislation, and decisions of the courts. In the UK, the relevant provision is:

> ...a person shall not store or gain access to information stored, in the terminal equipment of a subscriber or user unless the requirements of
>   paragraph (2) are met.
>
> (2) The requirements are that the subscriber or user of that terminal
>   equipment— (a) is provided with clear and comprehensive information
>   about the purposes of the storage of, or access to, that information;
>   and (b) has given his or her consent.

It isn't clear from this text alone what "terminal equipment" is, or what the exact scope of "information" is. Other case law suggests that "information" is more narrowly construed than "data," but it's still not very precise.

Consequently, most website operators have to fall back on the guidance offered by governmental agencies. In the UK, that guidance is essentially that *any* use of a cookie is subject to a consent requirement, whatever data is stored, for whatever purpose.

This may, or may not, be what the law actually requires; and the law may, or may not, address the real problem. But most website operators don't have access to specialist lawyers, and have little alternative than to follow governmental guidelines.